# Create random values in vector Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, random

I have this vector:

Population = [3, 5, 0, 2, 0, 5, 10, 50, 0, 1];

And i need to fill this vector with  a random value between 1 and 4 only where have 0 value in vector.

How i can do it ?

Edit: there's a way to do it using randperm function?

Comment: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, find zero elements, then generate random values, then replace those elements:

```
Population = [3, 5, 0, 2, 0, 5, 10, 50, 0, 1];
idx = find(Population==0);
Population(idx) = 3 * rand(size(idx)) + 1;
```

If you need integers (didn't specify), just round the generated random numbers in the last statement, like this `round(3*rand(size(idx))+1)`; or use `randi` (as suggested in answer by @OmG): `randi([1,4], size(idx))`.

Comment: Hi! Find(population==0) will return an array with the index of values?

Comment: @Jokesonme, Yes, in your example, it'll return vector: ``[3, 5, 9]``.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
ind = find(~Population); % find zero places
Population(ind) = randi(4,1,length(ind)); % replace them with a random integer
```